# break LHS into multiple lines for conditional function

Tags: equations, line-breaking, cases

This is what I have right now:

```
\begin{numcases}{\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{P}_{err})[n],\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{P}_{cor})[n^\prime]) = }
XXXXXXX
\end{numcases}
```

and it does not look good because the LHS take too much space marked by the red bounding box that squeezes my RHS which is the more important bit. So instead of this
[image]

How can I have this:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `aligned`, or `multlined`. Preferable, for subscripts which words or acronymes, use the `\text` command, to have a correct letterspacing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools,cases}
%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{\begin{aligned}\mathcal{F}( & \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{P}_\text{err})[n],\\&\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{P}_\text{cor})[n^\prime]) \end{aligned}= }
XXXXXXX \\ YYYYYYYY \\ ZZZZZZZ
\end{numcases}

\begin{numcases}{\begin{multlined}\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{P}_\text{err})[n],\\\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{P}_\text{cor})[n^\prime]) \end{multlined}= }
XXXXXXX \\ YYYYYYYY \\ ZZZZZZZ
\end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

[image]